# Display Business on Google Map

Tags: google, map, google-maps

I want to be able to display my company on Google Maps. I have a places page set up. If you search for it Google will show my business with a red marker which links to my places page.

I want it to display on the map all the time. Like the TM Lewin Shop in the example below.

[image]

[Map Link](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=london&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Westminster,%20London,%20United%20Kingdom&gl=uk&ll=51.497054,-0.138622&spn=0.001334,0.003484&z=19&iwloc=lyrftr:m,8025719665819214404,51.497219,-0.138507)

How do I get it to do that. What does Google use to decide that.

There are 3 business at our address. One of the companies is displayed on the map. Would that stop us displaying?

Answer (score 2):

I think your question at the end may be the problem. Google say

> There shouldn't be more than one
>   listing per physical location. Even if
>   you're a doctor who is a cardiologist
>   and a chiropractor or a service that
>   covers multiple towns, you shouldn't
>   have two listings. Instead, use the
>   description of your business or
>   categories to explain the different
>   services your business offers.

http://www.google.com/support/places/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=28247&topic=28292&answer=142902&from=28062&rd=1

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in [Google Places](http://www.google.com/places/). I'm not sure how they handle three businesses. I would guess that they choose the one most relevant to a search query.

Comment: Just entering London as search term.